# Install vmware workstation 11 from the terminal

Tags: vmware

How can I download and install VMware Workstation 11 from the terminal? We currently don't have a desktop gui installed (because of other reasons), if possible can i just download and install it from the terminal?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use

> curl --user name:password http://www.link_to_vmware_package.com/

or

> curl http://www.link_to_vmware_package.com/

if it doesn`t require login